# Inputting info into dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm currently working on a project and a dynamic array is a requirement. My array starts with up to 5 elements, and if the user inputs a number larger than 5 the array resizes. Whenever I enter information into the resized array and then try to output what was entered, I keep getting issues. At times it works and at times it doesn't.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int size = 5;
int classes;
//This is how I created the original array.
int* arr = { new int[size] {} };

//this is how my code is working right now
cout << "Enter the number of classes: ";
cin >> classes;
if(classes > size)  {
    size_t newSize = size * 2;
    int* resize_arr = new int[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
        resize_arr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    size = newSize;
    
    delete[] arr;
    arr = resize_arr;

}
for(int i = 0; i < classes; i++)  {
   cin >> arr[i]
}

for(int i = 0; i < classes; i++   {
   cout << arr[i]
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`?

Comment: This program won't even compile. The value `size` is not defined anywhere and the program contains multiple syntax errors. Please explain in detail the exact "issues" you're having. Provide valid code, and show example input/output that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Here, since you are iterating from 0 to `newSize`, you are guaranteed to access `arr` out-of-bounds, since the size of `arr` is `newSize/2`: `for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) resize_arr[i] = arr[i];`

Answer (score 1):

A very likely candidate for "issues" is the loop:

```
size_t newSize = size * 2;
int* resize_arr = new int[newSize];
for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
    resize_arr[i] = arr[i];
}
size = newSize;
```

You are copying `newSize` elements from an array that contained only `size` elements, resulting in out-of-bounds access. You should only copy `size` elements, not `newSize`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    resize_arr[i] = arr[i];
}
```